# How to press windows key + 1 using vb script

Tags: windows-7, vbscript

I would like to press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+ <kbd>1</kbd> using vb script to open my browser and other tools from my windows taskbar. according this [vbs scripts related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576365/send-windows-key-in-vbs) **VBScript's SendKeys doesn't support the Windows key.**.
It there any way to solve this problem

My OS is: windows 7

Comment: Looks like you may not be able to achieve this without additional software support... such as AutoIt...

Comment: [What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029)

Comment: yes @Kinnectus, i only want to native tools like vbs or bat. It's there any possibility?

Comment: @gronostaj Thank you for your guidance, question updated

Comment: Don't use taskbar order for this, it's not constant. Bring windows into focus by process name or something. Maybe you could do it with Powershell, but I don't have any experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a process using the `WScript` method named `Shell` or by using the `Shell` object and `ShellExecute`.

You can either hardcode the processes to start or you can make a batch file to start them and execute the batch from vbscript. etc. etc.

[Shell object documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Wscript execution example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866231/vbscript-start-a-process)

Comment: There are also DDE (or similar) interfaces to many programs. `Sendkeys` is almost always the wrong way. It is possible (however unlikely) for a program to steal focus before you send the keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue this was my solution:

Create a .VB file then convert it to an .EXE

The VB Script should look like this, Don't miss the first 2 lines and the last line not in the script box.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Module SendWinKey

    Const KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H0
    Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Integer = &H2

    Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "User32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, ByVal dwExtraInfo As UInteger)

       Public Sub Main()    
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.LWin), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0) 'press the left Win key down
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.1), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0) 'press the Left arrow key down
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.1), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) 'release the Left arrow key
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.LWin), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) 'release the left Win key
       End Sub
End Module"
```

Save it. From the command prompt run the following command. BE SURE TO REPLACE ***LATEST_VERSION*** WITH YOUR VERSION OF .NET FRAMEWORK, AND REPLACE ****FILE_LOCATION**** WITH THE LOCATION YOU SAVED THE FILE

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\***LATEST_VERSION***\vbc "C:\****FILE_LOCATION****\PushMyButtonsBaby.vb" /out:"C:\****FILE_LOCATION****\PushMyButtonsBaby.exe" /target:winexe`

Your antivirus may detect this as something like "Heur.AdvML.B" virus, but it is a false positive SEP caught it on mine as this. You may have to set the .EXE as an exclusion.

Hope this helps. It took me a while to find this solution.